# Cplex distributed parallel optimization setup issue [ Could not load worker : -13 ]

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, distributed, cplex, failed-installation

I am a new practitioner of IBM **[cplex](/questions/tagged/cplex)** distributed optimization and I have followed the steps listed on the IBM web pages about that matter, however there is a part of the set up process that is not working well: the starting process of a worker machine.

IBM describes that next is the main instruction to start a worker machine:

```
c:\folder_1\folder_2> cplex -worker= tcpip -libpath= c:\folder_1\folder_2 -address= ip:port
```

But I am getting next error:

> `Could not load worker : -13`

Has someone had such problem setting up a worker machine and how could it be solved?

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. **[1]** Tell us first, what have you tried so far and with what results? **[2]** This is a commercial, paid product, have you contacted the IBM Cplex support line and what was the result from them? **[3]** Post here what did your terminal show once you have run **`nmap -p`** `<_port#_> <_ip_>` **to see whether the remote host is ready at all, ok?**

Comment: Which instructions are you following exactly? Please put the link in your question. Which version of CPLEX are you using?

Comment: thanks guys. the basic instruction is to start the worker computer with this command: c:\folder_1\folder_2> cplex -worker=tcpip -libpath=c:\folder_1\folder_2 -address=ip:port, ip and port belong to the worker. And cplex is throwing out -> cplex error 1813. I am using cplex 12.6.3

Comment: I forgot to add the link: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/ibm-search-results?&q=distributed%20parallel%20optimization&page=1&documentId=78e1effda184b94e2f79b6e1dc9c210c

Comment: Are you looking at [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/distribMIP/09_tcp_ip.html) page in the documentation? Have all of the .dll files from the `bin` directory in the CPLEX installation directory been copied to `c:\folder_1\folder_2`? For example, `cplex1263.dll`, `cplex1263processworker.dll`, etc. Can you try upgrading to the latest version (currently 12.7.1)?

Comment: Yes, I am running 12.7, and Iam running directly in the bin cplex path. This can give you more lights: I ran directly using oplrun the example distmip and see the results -> it is strange that one of the workers says that has not memory:

Comment: <<< setup
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 1028 rows and 28 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 32 coefficients.
Aggregator did 1 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 1118 rows, 36 columns, and 9404 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 36 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.03 sec. (11.93 ticks)
Running distributed MIP on 2 solvers.
Setting up 2 distributed solvers.
Setup time = 0.02 sec. (0.00 ticks)
Starting ramp-up.
Ramp-up finished (winner: -1).

Comment: Ramp-up time = 0.02 sec. (0.00 ticks)
*** ERROR[ENGINE_002] at 33:0 C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\opl\examples\opl\distMIP\lifegameip_main.mod: Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.
*** ERROR[ENGINE_002] at 33:0 C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\opl\examples\opl\distMIP\lifegameip_main.mod: Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX status = 1001.
main returns -2

Comment: stackoverflow is not conducive for this type of troubleshooting. I suggest that you re-post your question on the IBM developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059).